Blazor ErrorContent not catching an error
Blazor Interactive Server - in my MainLayout.razor I have:
<ErrorBoundary>
    <ChildContent>
        <!-- lots of nodes -->
    </ChildContent>
    <ErrorContent Context="error">
        <main class="page--error">
            <div class="main-content">
                @{
                    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    Logger.LogError(error, $"{error.GetType().Name}: {guid}");
                }
                <h1>Unexpected Error (sorry)</h1>
                <p>
                    The program has encountered an unexpected error (yes there are expected errors). This error has been
                    logged and we will look at it.
                </p>
            </div>
        </main>
    </ErrorContent>
</ErrorBoundary>

When it throws an exception handling an event in one of my components, it never gets to the <ErrorContent>. Why not?
And what do I need to do to log the exception? I want to avoid having to try/catch everywhere just to log the exception.
In addition this occurs silently. No error is displayed to the user. I want to put up a message that says something happened, provide them an error number (guid) and ask them to contact support. I can then use that guid to find the issue in the logs to see what happened.
The code throwing the exception is fired off by OnSelectResources:
<SelectOrganizations Data="@_allOrganizations"
                     Visible="@IsSelectResourcesVisible"
                     Click="@OnSelectResources"/>

Which is:
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<IEnumerable<Organization>?> Click { get; set; }

Which is declared as:
<DxButton RenderStyle="ButtonRenderStyle.Primary"
          Text="@Localizer["Select"]"
          Enabled="@(Values?.Count() > 0 && Values?.Count() <= @MaxAllowSelected)"
          Click="OnSelect" />

And calls:
private void OnSelect()
{
    Visible = false;
    _receivedClick = true;
    if (Click.HasDelegate)
        Click.InvokeAsync(Values);
}

Update: As stated above, this is InteractiveServer mode. In App.razor I have:
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
</head>
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />


As mentioned in the document:

In Blazor Web Apps with the error boundary only applied to a static
MainLayout component, the boundary is only active during static
server-side rendering (static SSR). The boundary doesn't activate just
because a component further down the component hierarchy is
interactive.
An interactive render mode can't be applied to the MainLayout
component because the component's Body parameter is a RenderFragment
delegate, which is arbitrary code and can't be serialized. To enable
interactivity broadly for the MainLayout component and the rest of the
components further down the component hierarchy, the app must adopt a
global interactive render mode by applying the interactive render mode
to the HeadOutlet and Routes component instances in the app's root
component, which is typically the App component. The following example
adopts the Interactive Server (InteractiveServer) render mode
globally.

<HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

...

<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

Update:
You may create a custom  errorBoundary and log the error in OnErrorAsync method
public class CustomErrorBoundary : ErrorBoundary
{
    [Inject]
    ILogger<CustomErrorBoundary> Logger { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override Task OnErrorAsync(Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(.....);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

replace
<ErrorBoundary>
....
</ErrorBoundary>

with
<CustomErrorBoundary>
  .....
</CustomErrorBoundary>

in mainlayout and remove the @block:
@{
  var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
  Logger.LogError(error, $"{error.GetType().Name}: {guid}");
 }


I do have it set to InteractiveServer. I'll update the question with this. thanks

Hi,@David Thielen, you may try with  custom errorboundary to log error and remove the @ block inside  ErrorContent,I've updated my answer,hopes help

Unless I'm doing something wrong this has the same problem - it's not called for exceptions that occur outside of the rendering.
